# Is cold coffee stronger than regular coffee?

Tags: health, iced-coffee

If we have to start our day with caffeine then can we take cold coffee instead of regular coffee? And what are the effects of cold coffee on our health?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cold brew generally has a higher concentration of caffeine due to the process of which it is made. Somewhere between 1:4 and 1:8 caffeine to water ratio. Whilst regular coffee is somewhere between 1:15 to 1:25.

If you want to dive deeper into the caffeine in cold brew, you can check out this link:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5740146/